# PhP get element by id not working

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to do a php file using DOM in order to append a few table rows to my table whenever my SQL table is updated. The problem is, the function getElementById never works and i don't get why. here's the code:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->validateOnParse = true; 
$doc->load('home.php');
$element = $doc->getElementById('table-responsive');   //this is a div
$teste = $doc->createElement('div');
$element->appendChild($test);
```

I always get error 500 because the getElementById is not found/ doesn't work.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Try using `$doc->loadHTML('home.php');`.

Comment: getElementById often doesn't work . Use instead  `$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$element = $xpath->query("//*[@id='table-responsive']")->item(0);`

Comment: tried the loadHTML, still no luck. i'll try that now @splash58

Comment: do i need any include to do that ?

Comment: No, it's native PHP library

Comment: i still get the error :/

Comment: Error 500, its right after i try to append the div to the element. i tried to echo the element and it says Null.

Comment: not null, empty string.

Comment: i think the problem is in the load

Comment: You create element `$teste` and adding `$test`. it's not the same